# How to decile a column in a dataframe by partitions in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to decile a sales column in my dataframe but also partition by year. So each year should have different deciles.

df = ['year','name', 'sales']

I think I can use this function but want to partition by year

df['decile']=pd.qcut(df['sales'],10,labels=False)

I suppose I can use groupby but I am not able to figure out the syntax.

Would really appreciate any help?

Comment: Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. Take a minute to read -> [How to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df['decile'] = df.groupby('year')[['sales'']].apply(lambda g: pd.qcut(g.rank(method='first'), 10, labels=False)+1)
```

Explain:

- `g.rank(method='first')`: in case there are many sales with same values. I add this one because in my experiment, I encountered many case where you have same values. If there is low chance of duplicated values, then you can replace by `g` which is fine.
- `10, labels=False)+1)`: you can leave option +1 if you want to label from 1 to 10. If not, it will label from 0 to 9